# Loading truststore and keystore using System.setProperty in java

Tags: java, ssl, soap, keystore, truststore

I am trying to create web service call for server in ssl,in order to load the certificates,I am using System.setProperty but it is not working if I am providing it seperately for one way and two way ssl.If I am providing it in the beginning,it is working fine.

Working scenario:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "\truststore.ts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "pwd");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "\serverkeystore.ks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "pwd");

call webservice for one way ssl.
call webservice for two way ssl
```

--

```
if(one way ssl)
{
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "\truststore.ts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "pwd");
call webservice();
}
```

Above two calls are working fine
Below code is not working

```
else if(two way ssl){
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "\truststore.ts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "pwd");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "\serverkeystore.ks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "pwd");
call webservice for two way ssl
}
```

Comment: You say *Non Working Scenario:* and have some code below that. Then below that code you say *Above call is working fine* - so which is it? is only your first block working, and the other two not working?

Comment: Ist two blocks are working,last one is not working

Comment: Ok so if `if(one way ssl)` is working, just throw an `else` in there then? Assuming the only other option is the mutual SSL.

Comment: edited the question,u have any idea why such behaviour

Comment: I would guess whatever you put in `else if(two way ssl){` is returning `false` and you might need to review whatever code that is.

Comment: I have two servers,one is in one way ssl other is in two wal ssl,for one server its working fine,but for other its not working and if I do in the way mentioned in block 1,it is working for both